# How to write responsive HTML?

Tags: html, responsive-design

It's easy to write responsive CSS, you just use media queries to check screen size.

But how can you rearrange HTML based on screen size? Based on different screen sizes you might want to place divs in completely different places.

FOR EXAMPLE:

Say I have the following layout on a 1000px screen:

```
[VIDEO] [SEARCH BAR]
[LIST OF STUFF]
[LOG IN/OUT][MENU]
```

But if the screen is resized to under 500px, I want the content to reorganize into this layout:

```
[MENU]
[LOG IN/OUT]
[SEARCH BAR]
[LIST OF STUFF]
[VIDEO]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @frontend_dev That looks like basically the same thing as adjusting CSS. My question is about literally moving divs around. I'll update my question.

Comment: Aside from moving things around on the page with positioning, margin/padding, displays, etc... I don't think it's possible to move items throughout the dom with html/css alone. I've "cheated" in the past with this and used hidden divs with `display: none` and simply added `block` to them with a resize, but this adds lots of redundant or unnecessary code. You'd have to look to javascript to actually move elements throughout the page.

Comment: Actually with flexboxes you can rearrange content, at least to a certain degree. For example swap collumns etc. But of course there are limits to that, since your content does not really move, but is layouted differently. But what you outlined might be actually possible. Give it a shot. Otherwise, you might need to shift DOM Elements around using js, which can be quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

What you are refering to is probably javascript, because once HTML is rendered, it cannot be modified, excepted by javascript. For responsive designs, what you want to achieve is made simple by common frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), or recently with [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in CSS.

Another simple way of doing this is with the css property `display`, which you can set to `none` when you want to hide a div depending on screen size (media queries, as you mentionned).

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should point out that with flexbox, you can re-arrange items with the order property - which is exactly what the OP is trying to do. "Responsive HTML" would be a nightmare and is never going to exist; and using JavaScript re rearrange items would be slow. The only proper way to do this is via CSS (including what you mentioned in your second paragraph).